# How can I render a catmull rom spline using jQuery SVG?

Tags: svg

I'm using jQuery SVG to render a simple 2D line graph, but I want to smooth it out by rendering it out as a catmull rom path.

SVG only supports bezier curves, so is there a way to calculate the control points in order to simulate catmull rom?

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using [d3.js](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/)? [This page](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes) documents using line.tension to create a Catmull-Rom spline.

Answer (score 2):

You also might consider using Raphael. You can easily render catmull rom splines using "R":

```
   var p = new Raphael(0, 0, "100%", "100%");

   p.path("M 100 100 R 100 200 300 300 300 10 400 400 200 200");
```

Raphael is available at http://raphaeljs.com/